# Function to create activity indicator in center of scroll view and tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a few VCs that all inherits from a BaseVC: UIViewController. Some of the VC has tableView/collection view embedded, I am creating a function that allows all VCs to create a activity indicator in the center of the table/collection/UIView with a function call like

```
activityIndicatorBegin(mytableView)
activityIndicatorBegin(myCollectionView)
activityIndicatorBegin(nil)
```

Below are my attempt and the error I am getting is a weird "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64". So I imagine this is not the proper way to do it

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func activityIndicatorBegin(scrollView: UIScrollView?) {
    if activityIndicator.isAnimating() == false {
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,20,20))
        activityIndicator.center.x = view.center.x
        activityIndicator.center.y = view.center.y - 100
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.blackColor()

        if let scrollView = scrollView {
            scrollView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        } else {
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        }
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

func activityIndicatorEnd() {
    if activityIndicator.isAnimating() == true {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "myAPP.BaseViewController.activityIndicatorBegin (__ObjC.UITableView?) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPP9VC1 in VC1.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPP14VC2 in VC2.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPPVC3 in VC3.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPP10VC4 in VC4.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPP10VC5 in VC5.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPP9VC6 in VC6.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC7myAPP6VC7 in VC7.o
```

Note I have multiple VC that is calling this function at the moment. Some are TableView, some are standard UIViewcontroller and some are CollectionView

Comment: Update your question with the actual errors, not a vague summary of the error. Details matter.

Comment: Updated. I wasnt sure if my syntax was OK to pass the tableView/CollectionView into the scrollView variable.